# Call a generic method without explicitly specifying the type-arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, generic-type-argument

My controller-base has the following handler:

```
protected ActionResult HandleRequest<TRequest, TResponse, TViewModel>(Func<TRequest, TResponse> function, TRequest request)
    where TRequest : BaseRequest
    where TResponse : BaseResponse<TViewModel> 
    where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    var viewData = function(request);

    return View(viewData);
}
```

Which is currently called like

```
return HandleRequest<HomeIndexGetRequest, HomeIndexGetResponse, HomeIndexGetViewModel>(GetData, request);
```

in my controller.
The GetData-method looks like

```
private static HomeIndexGetResponse GetData(HomeIndexGetRequest request)
{
    return new HomeIndexGetResponse
        {
            ViewModel = new HomeIndexGetViewModel()
        };
}
```

The `HomeIndexGetResponse` signature is

```
public class HomeIndexGetResponse : BaseResponse<HomeIndexGetViewModel>
```

And `BaseResponse` is setup like

```
public abstract class BaseResponse<TViewModel> where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
```

Question: Is there any chance that I can call the HandleRequest without specifying the type-arguments explicitly?

```
return HandleRequest(GetData, request);
```

Comment: What happens if you try? The compiler does some type inferencing but gives up with multiple layers.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'ActionResult MvcApplication1.Controllers.MasterController.HandleRequest<TRequest,TResponse,TViewModel>(Func<TRequest,TResponse>, TRequest)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around a bit I came up with the following solution which works as I need it.

New non-generic base class

```
public abstract class BaseResponse
```

Changed the BaseResponse to

```
public abstract class BaseResponse<TViewModel> : BaseResponse where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
```

The handler changed to

```
protected ActionResult HandleRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(Func<TRequest, TResponse> function, TRequest request)
    where TRequest : BaseRequest
    where TResponse : BaseResponse 
{
    var viewData = function(request);

    return View(viewData);
}
```

without the TViewModel type-argument.

Finally, the controller looks like this

```
return HandleRequest(GetData, request);
```

In the action, and the `GetData` is implemented

```
private static BaseResponse GetData(HomeIndexGetRequest request)
{
    return new HomeIndexGetResponse
        {
            ViewModel = new HomeIndexGetViewModel()
        };
}
```